# Colnames by a vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to create an empty matrix with the col and row names:

```
tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
col_names <- unique(tbl)

mat_master_EOD <- matrix(0, nrow = length(data_rd[,1]),ncol = 82)
colnames(mat_master_EOD) <- col_names
rownames(mat_master_EOD) <- data_rd[,1]
```

That's how the names of columns should look like.

```
> tbl
 [1] "F1.csv"  "F10.csv" "F11.csv" "F12.csv" "F13.csv" "F14.csv" "F15.csv" "F16.csv" "F17.csv" "F18.csv"
[11] "F19.csv" "F2.csv"  "F20.csv" "F3.csv"  "F4.csv"  "F5.csv"  "F6.csv"  "F7.csv"  "F8.csv"  "F9.csv"
```

The problem is that I have 80 columns and only 20 names. I would like to set 4 columns for each name and first should be "Accession" and second "Description". That's how it should be:

```
Accession Description F1.csv_1 F1.csv_2 F1.csv_3 F1.csv_4 F2.csv_1 F2.csv_2 F2.csv_3 and so on...
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible (and I don't understand why you'd want it). You could create an 20*4*nrow array and only name two dimensions.

Comment: I don't exactly what you mean but I'd like to keep all the data in one table.

Comment: I also don't know exactly what you mean. Either all columns of a matrix are named or none. There is no in-between. You probably should restructure your data.

Comment: I want to name all of the columns. First -> Accession, Second -> Description, after that 4 columns with the name F1~, than 4 columns with the name F2~, than 4 columns F3~ and 4 columns F4~ and so on. Until I reach the number of F20~. So in total it gives 82 named columns. I can do it manually of course by creating a vector but I am lazy to write all of those names. Hope I explained well now. EDITED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to create four names per 'col_names':

```
col_names <- c("F1.csv",  "F10.csv")
paste0(rep(col_names, each = 4), "_", 1:4)
# [1] "F1.csv_1"  "F1.csv_2"  "F1.csv_3"  "F1.csv_4"  "F10.csv_1" "F10.csv_2" "F10.csv_3"
# [8] "F10.csv_4"
```

Comment: name_cols <- paste0(rep(col_names, each = 4), "_", 1:4)
name_columns <- c("Accession", "Description", name_cols). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you think it is possible to sort them ? > head(name_cols)
[1] "F1.csv_1"  "F1.csv_2"  "F1.csv_3"  "F1.csv_4"  "F10.csv_1" "F10.csv_2". I would like to have F2 after the F1 instead of F10...

Comment: If the 'col_names' are as regular as you describe them, you could just create the names from scratch: `paste0("F", rep(1:20, each = 4), ".csv_", 1:4)`.